# Create a user using Twilio Programmable Chat JavaScript SDK

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I create a Client and a **private** Channel I join. Then trying to add another user using:

```
Channel.add(identity)
```

I get

```
50200 - User not found
```

I know a member has to be a user first. How do I create a user using the JavaScript SDK?

EDIT:
The most important part of [philnash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28376/philnash) answer is `The first time a new Identity is encountered by Chat`. So, I just created another client using this identity and it actually has created the user. Simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You don't explicitly create users from the JavaScript SDK, [from the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/api/users):

> The first time a new Identity is encountered by Chat within a Service instance, a new User instance will be created using the Identity encountered.
>   If the Identity exists, the existing User record will be used for that session/request. This is true for endpoints and Access Tokens, and for creating Members in a POST to the Members resource.

If you need to use a user before the identity is encountered via the SDK, then you can [create a user using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/api/users#create-a-user).